# Xamarin Forms: Grouping ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, listview, binding, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a `ListView` binded to `ObservableCollection<Request>`. Here's `Request` class:

```
public class Request
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RequestName { get; set; }
    public string Provider { get; set; }
    public int Done { get; set; }
}
```

I have only 2 possible values in `Done`: `0` or `1`. `Request`s that have `Done` set to `0` to one group, others to other group. How is it possible to do this?

Comment: Maybe this links will help you: http://motzcod.es/post/94643411707/enhancing-xamarinforms-listview-with-grouping or https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17976/listview-grouping-example-please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you would group it. You may need to enhance on this further to make it a bit more user friendly.

**Grouped Property**

```
private ObservableCollection<Grouping<String, Request>> _groupedList = null;
public ObservableCollection<Grouping<String, Request>> GroupedList {
    get {
        return _groupedList;
    }
    set {
        _groupedList = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => GroupedList);
    }
}
```

**Creating List**

```
var list = new List<Request>();

var grouped = from Model in list
                         group Model by Model.Done into Group
                         select new Grouping<string, Request>(Group.Key, Group);

GroupedList = new ObservableCollection<Grouping<string, TModel>>(grouped);
```

**The ListView Xaml**

```
<ListView IsGroupingEnabled="true" HasUnevenRows="true">
    <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>                
                <Label Text="{Binding Key}" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.View>
                <ContentView Padding="10">
                    <Label Text={Binding RequestName}" />
                </ContentView>
                </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```